# Jest Unit Test Method Fails for the Catch Block

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the following methods in a TypeScript class:

```
  protected async getItem (key: DocumentClient.Key, consistentRead?: boolean): Promise<Item | undefined> {
    const dynamoDbResult = await this.documentClient.get({
      Key: key,
      TableName: this.tableName,
      ConsistentRead: consistentRead
    }).promise().catch(error => {
      this.logAWSError('Failed to get an item from the DynamoDb', error)
      throw error
    })

  protected logAWSError (message: string, errorObject: AWSError): void {
    console.log(`${message}. AWS Error code : ${errorObject.code} AWS Error message : ${errorObject.message} AWS Error stack : ${String(errorObject.stack)} AWS Error originalError : ${String(errorObject.originalError?.message)}`)
  }
```

And I try to write unit test method with jest for the **catch** block of the **getItem** method like following. Please note that I haven't put the whole code here, but when I run the unit test, it goes into the catch block and as you see in the log, the correct console log is printed.

```
  const dummyAWSError: AWSError = {
     name: 'dummyAWSError',
     message: 'AWS can not be reached',
     stack: 'DummyStackTrace',
     code: '234',
     time: new Date('2021-01-01')
  }

  test('it should throw the AWS Error when getting item from DynamoDB', async () => {
    documentClient.get = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ promise: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(dummyAWSError) })
    await expect(repository.getItem(key)).rejects.toThrowError(dummyAWSError)
  })
```

But the test fails!:

```
expect(received).rejects.toThrowError(expected)

Expected message: "AWS can not be reached"

Received function did not throw

  139 |   test('it should throw the AWS Error when getting item from DynamoDB', async () => {
  140 |     documentClient.get = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ promise: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(dummyAWSError) })
> 141 |     await expect(repository.getItem(key)).rejects.toThrowError(dummyAWSError)
      |                                                   ^
  142 |   })
  143 |
  144 |   test('it should return undefined when a specific item is not found', async () => {

  at Object.toThrowError (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:241:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/repositories/abstract.repository.spec.ts:141:51)

  console.log
      Failed to get an item from the DynamoDb. AWS Error code : 234 AWS Error message : AWS can not be reached AWS Error stack : DummyStackTrace AWS Error originalError : undefined

      at DummyRepository.logAWSError (src/repositories/abstract.repository.ts:269:13)
```

Do you have any idea/comment/solution please?

Comment: You are expecting repository.getItem() to reject, but I do not see that defined in your test.

Comment: The repository is defined. But I haven't put this code here.

Comment: The problem was resolved when I use the "ToBe" instead of "ToThrowError": await expect(repository.getItem(key)).rejects.toBe(dummyAWSError)